# NLTK: Converting raw string to normal string

Tags: string, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I have got an article from NLTK's Reuters corpora, as a raw string

```
>>>from nltk.corpus import reuters
>>>retail_article = reuters.raw('training/8173')
>>>print (retail_article)

"FRENCH GDP SHOULD RISE 2.3 PCT IN 1988 - MINISTRY\n  French gross domestic 
 product should grow\n  by 2.3 pct in 1988 after two pct growth this year 
 and 2.1 pct\n  in 1986, the Finance Ministry said.\n      The latest 
 forecast,...
```

Instead of `\n`, I want the text to be in a separate line. How can I do the same?

```
>>>type(retail_article)
str
```

`decode()` doesn't work on strings, and `encode()` is not giving the desired results.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The output you show is not generated by writing `print(retail_article)`. Clearly you typed just `retail_article` at the interpreter prompt. The difference is significant, and it seems to be the source of your confusion.

No conversion is necessary. A "raw" string is a way of writing a literal string. The corpus reader's `raw()` method does not return a "raw string", it just returns a string. (The method name refers to the fact that no processing is done; the exact content of the file(s) is returned.)

Your string `retail_article` contains actual newlines, not `\`, `n` sequences. To see the newlines, use `print(retail_article)`. When you just write `retail_article` at the command prompt, you get an unambiguous representation of the string (the so-called "repr" form)-- what you were looking at.